# How to access specific data pairs in csv_reader files python?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, reader

I have CSV file that contains data pairs exported from a spectrum analyzer software. I am coding in python.

I need to get the individual data pairs and have tried this two ways: one using numpy and one using the csv module
when using numpy I have tried loadtxt and genfromtxt. The issue I run into is with both of those when I print it it has a "b" character in front of it such as :(b'-0.0001835, 4.27E-05'). Thus, I cannot do operations on those floats because they aren't read as floats.

Using the csv_module my code looks like :

```
import csv

f = open('/Users/kaitlynmckee/Downloads/python_try.csv')

csv_f = csv.reader(f) #opens data w/out b flag 

for row in csv_f:
    print(row)  
    print("Test 1!")
    print(float(row))

data = []

for row in csv_f:
    data[row] = float(row(1))

print("You are the coolest")
print (data)
```

It throws an error with the "print(float(row))" part, because you can only pass it one part at a time, I guess. However, I got an error earlier trying to index a csv reader file.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library, which usually makes working with numerical CSV data way simpler.

Comment: What does the print(row) line actually print?

Comment: Please show the code that you wrote using numpy's `loadtxt` or `genfromtxt`, and also show a sample of the actual file you are reading.  The fix for your numpy code might be as simple as adding `delimiter=','` when you call `loadtxt` or `genfromtxt`.

Answer (score 0):

The `b` flag is Python3's way of display byte strings.  Normally Py3 uses unicode strings, so byte strings are displayed differently.  It's Py3 way of displaying a string read from a plain ascii text file.

With `csv` questions, you really should give a small sample of the file you are trying to read.  But my guess is that you just have 2 columns of floats.  If so, `np.loadtxt` or `np.genfromtxt` should have no problem loading it.  Using the `csv.reader` is probably more work than it's worth, though it does handle quoted strings (with blanks) better.

`pandas` also has a powerful (and fast) `csv` loader.

If your file just has 2 columns of floats, than the result from one of the `numpy` loaders will a 2d `numpy` array.  Each rows will be one of your data pairs.

I may add a simple example, but it would be better if I started with your sample file.

If my sample file is:

```
-0.0001835, 4.27E-05
-0.0001835, 4.27E-05
-0.0001835, 4.27E-05

In [77]: np.loadtxt('test.csv')
...

ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'-0.0001835,'
```

With an error like this, the fix, as @Warren notes, is as simple as adding the delimiter parameter:

```
In [78]: np.loadtxt('test.csv',delimiter=',')
Out[78]: 
array([[ -1.83500000e-04,   4.27000000e-05],
       [ -1.83500000e-04,   4.27000000e-05],
       [ -1.83500000e-04,   4.27000000e-05]])
```

---

With `csv` I could do:

```
In [89]: f=open('test.csv')                      
In [90]: csv_f=csv.reader(f)
In [91]: data=[]
In [92]: for row in csv_f:                       
    data.append(row)
   ....:     
In [93]: data
Out[93]: 
[['-0.0001835', ' 4.27E-05'],
 ['-0.0001835', ' 4.27E-05'],
 ['-0.0001835', ' 4.27E-05']]
In [94]: np.array(data)
Out[94]: 
array([['-0.0001835', ' 4.27E-05'],
       ['-0.0001835', ' 4.27E-05'],
       ['-0.0001835', ' 4.27E-05']], 
      dtype='<U10')
In [95]: np.array(data,float)
Out[95]: 
array([[ -1.83500000e-04,   4.27000000e-05],
       [ -1.83500000e-04,   4.27000000e-05],
       [ -1.83500000e-04,   4.27000000e-05]])
```